# Swift Type Cast from Parent/Base to Child class

Tags: ios, swift, oop, inheritance

I have parent/base class as below:

```
class Base {
    ...
}
```

Also, having the child class as below:

```
class Child: Base {
    ...
    func someFunc() {

    }
}
```

I have created the instances of Parent class as below:

```
let baseObj = Base()
```

Now, I want to call the method of Child class from the parent object. So I have code like below:

```
let childObj = baseObj as! Child
childObj.someFunc()
```

But this is giving me runtime crash like below:

```
Could not cast value of type 'PCTests.Base' (0x11c6ad150) to 'PCTests.Child' (0x11c6ab530).
```

Comment: Your `Child` class is (despite its name) *not* a child class of `Base`. You have defined two unrelated classes. It is unclear to me what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @MartinR: Sorry there was an error in code. I have updated the same. Thanks for pointing. But my actual code is actually the child of parent class.

Answer (score 5):

Error says it all.... You cannot typecast parent into child object. Thats not how inheritance works.

Comment: Yes, I know that this is not the way to do it but can you please provide me any alternate solution to achieve that. One of the solution is to create different instance for child class, but I want to avoid that if I have any other solution.

Comment: I am afraid thats against Object Orientation Programming. Why would you do that? With parent child relationship, you cannot call child specific functionalities from parent object. If you end up in a situation where you have to, sit back and think on your application design. May be you want some other design pattern here.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by making object of child class actually, and you should keep structure in that way as this is core concept of Base and child class, if you do following it should work:

```
let baseObj = Child()
```

Now in base class you can do following

```
let childObj = self as! Child
childObj.someFunc()
```

Whereas `someFunc` is defined in child class.

P.S. Would be my pleasure to clarify if it doesn't make sense for you, thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
let childObj = baseObj
switch childObj {
    case let _child as Child: 
        _child.someFunc()
    default: break
}
```

Comment: Reference of Child class will not equal to Instance of Parent class.